# -eq and -ne give me the same results

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, domaincontroller

Why do the following two command, with the only difference the -eq and -ne operator give me my list of DCs?

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {(operatingsystem -like "*server*") -AND 
(PrimaryGroup -eq "CN=Domain Controllers,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com") } 
-Property Name,PrimaryGroup
```

I'd expect this one to have everything, but domain controllers.

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {(operatingsystem -like "*server*") -AND 
(PrimaryGroup -ne "CN=Domain Controllers,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com") } 
-Property Name,PrimaryGroup
```

If I run the equivalent against PrimaryGroupID instead of PrimaryGroup, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I actually get an error when trying both commands. Did a little digging and the filter was causing the problem. Had a quick look in ADSIEdit at a server object. It doesn't appear to have a attribute called "PrimaryGroup".

This was in a 2008 R2 AD running in 2008 R2 forest and domain functional levels.

As an aside, if you want a list of DC in a domain get-ADDomainController will do the job.

regards
Arcass

Comment: I actually want all servers except DCs. In the output of the command on the domain I'm working on, it lists PrimaryGroup so I should be able filter against it, no?

Comment: @flickerfly Could you add in your OP how do you list the 'PrimaryGroup' attribute? In the ActiveDirectory Schema it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put one statement on separate lines, you need to put the backtick (`) at the end of the line to tell PowerShell that the statement continues on the next line. However, even then, you cannot split the filter on two different lines. So it should look something like this:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {(operatingsystem -like "*server*") -AND (PrimaryGroup -eq "CN=Domain Controllers,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com") } `
    -Property Name,PrimaryGroup
```

As you've found, AD doesn't actually have an attribute called `PrimaryGroup`. That is a property that PowerShell exposes to you, which interprets the value in the `primaryGroupId` attribute for you.

The [`primaryGroupId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-primarygroupid) attribute of any object has the Relative Identifier (RID) of the group. The RID is the last section of number in the SID, but the group also stores this value in its [`primaryGroupToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-primarygrouptoken) atrribute. So you can get this value like this:

```
$primaryGroupToken = (Get-ADGroup "Domain Controllers" -Properties primaryGroupToken).primaryGroupToken
```

PowerShell has to convert what you pass into the `-Filter` parameter into a proper LDAP query, so when you use `PrimaryGroup` in the filter, PowerShell is doing that for you.

However, doing that lookup is not really necessary in this case, because the [Domain Controllers group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/active-directory-security-groups#bkmk-domaincontrollers) is a built-in group and always has an RID of `516`. So you can do what you're trying to do like this:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter "operatingsystem -like '*server*' -AND PrimaryGroupId -eq 516" `
    -Property Name,PrimaryGroup
```